# Hover-over Image function: how can I set its dimension by percentage and how to simplify this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a image-effect code that achieves the following:
**1)** Combines `background-blend-mode: multiply` and `filter: saturation 0%`
**2)** Upon hovering over the image, the image reverts back to its original color palette.

I'm hoping you all can help me achieve the following goals:
**1)** How can I determine the **image's width by percentage** while the **height is set to `auto`**? Example: width: 50%; height: auto 
**2)** How can I **simplify this code** so it isn't so chunky? I feel like this code can be structured more efficiently...
**3)** How can I make the width of the image correspond to the `.page` wrapper?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/jh7um0ov/) for visual / functional reference.

This is a Visualization of what I need help achieving
*(**Left:** Current, **Right:** Goal)*

[image]

Below is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page">

<div class="image-wrap-01">
    <div class="image01">
        <svg>
            <defs>
                <filter id="colorize_brown" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                    <feFlood flood-color="#8E4204" result="A" />
                    <feColorMatrix type="saturate" in="SourceGraphic" values="0" result="B" />
                    <feBlend mode="multiply" in2="B" in="A" />
                </filter>
            </defs>
            <image class="brown" filter="url(#colorize_brown)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://i59.tinypic.com/1zvwwv9.jpg" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <p class="caption01">Image 001</p>
</div> <!-- END | image-wrap-01 -->

<div class="image-wrap-02">
    <div class="image02">
        <svg>
            <defs>
                <filter id="colorize_brown" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                    <feFlood flood-color="#8E4204" result="A" />
                    <feColorMatrix type="saturate" in="SourceGraphic" values="0" result="B" />
                    <feBlend mode="multiply" in2="B" in="A" />
                </filter>
            </defs>
            <image class="brown" filter="url(#colorize_brown)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://i60.tinypic.com/nwzvpx.jpg" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <p class="caption02">Image 002</p>
</div> <!-- END | image-wrap-02 -->

</div> <!-- END | .page -->
```

**CSS:**

```
/* PAGE WRAP */
.page {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #ffecae;
}

/* IMAGE 01 */
.image-wrap-01 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.image01, .image01 svg {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
.image01 {
    background: url("http://i59.tinypic.com/1zvwwv9.jpg");
    background-size: 600px 400px;
    position: relative;
}

/* IMAGE 02 */
.image-wrap-02 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.image02, .image02 svg {
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
}
.image02 {
    background: url("http://i60.tinypic.com/nwzvpx.jpg");
    background-size: 400px 600px;
    position: relative;
}

/* UNIVERSAL COMMAND */
.image01 svg, .image02 svg {
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

/* HOVEROVER */
.brown {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.brown:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */
.caption01 {
    text-align: left;
    font: 13px/17px helvetica;
    color: black;
    width: 600px;
}

.caption02 {
    text-align: right;
    font: 13px/17px helvetica;
    color: black;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answers your question:

The images are now the full width of the column. The only thing you need to manually code in is the aspect ratio of the image as `padding-top:150%;`, which is the same as the responsive solution for embedding youtube/vimeo videos into a website.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpither/6x0apqod/

Let me know if I interpreted your question wrong.

Comment: hi @ryanpither thank you for the answer, but in the jsfiddle you provided me the images are still outside of the column...

Comment: I don't think my save worked, so it's pretty much what you originally had. I'll redo it tonight and submit a new URL.